# AT command to put the A6 GSM/GPRS into sleep / power down

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, communication

The general AT command for sleep mode (for the SIMCOM GSM modules) is AT+CSCLK=1 (or AT+CSCLK=2). I have given both a shot but they don't work with the A6 module. Does anyone know of any other command that does the same? The manufacturers claim that it can function at very low current levels when in sleep. But sadly they don't mention the sleep AT command.

Answer (score 1):

A6 module uses a hardware pin (INT/GPIO_1) or (EN) enable on some modules.
There is no AT command as in the SIM900.